# Ignorar atributos de uma classe usando DataMember C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

Estou tentando retornar um json de uma controller ignorando alguns dos campos do mesmo.

**Controller:**

```
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult Get()
    {
        var result = _service.Generate();

        if (result == null)
            BadRequest();

        return Json(result);
    }
```

**Minha service retorna uma view model:**

```
[DataContract]
public class MenuViewMapping
{
    public MenuViewMapping()
    {
        Children = new List<MenuViewMapping>();
    }
    [DataMember]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Permissions { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public string Url { get; set; }
    public bool VisibleWithNoChild { get; set; }
    [DataMember]
    public List<MenuViewMapping> Children { get; set; }
}
```

Estou tentando fazer com que os campos `Permissions` e `VisibleWithNoChild` sejam ignorados na hora de retornar o Json. Minha service basicamente lê um json e monta os objetos para montar um menu dinâmico.

Ele chega na controller com todas as informações, mas não ignora os atributos acima.

Comment: De uma olhada na resposta que dei na pergunta acima, você pode usar o atributo `JsonIgnore`.

Comment: Deu certo, eu use o `JsonIgnore` e fiz o retorno como `Ok(result)`, só precisei fazer uma serialização antes de retornar o result. Deu certo! Valeu :D